# D3 line chart and adding data points real time

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am beginner to d3 and trying to create real time chart which adds in new values on the go. I want the chart to shift the old points to the left as new points are added. Below is my code but for some reason, the browser freezes with the code (I have commented out the .on() line in the end that causes the freeze).

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js">
    
  </script>
  <script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js">
    
  </script>
  <script>
    var t = -1;
    var n = 40;
    var duration = 750;

    var data = [];

    console.log('hello');
    function next() {
      return {
        time: ++t,
        value: Math.random() * 10
      }
    }

    var margin = {
        top: 6,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 20,
        left: 40
      },
      width = 560 - margin.right,
      height = 120 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain([t - n + 1, t])
      .range([0, width]);

    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 10])
      .range([height, 0]);

    var line = d3.line()
      .x((d) => xScale(d.time))
      .y((d) => yScale(d.value));

    var svg = d3.select('body').append('p').append('svg');

    var chartArea = svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

    chartArea.append('defs').append('clipPath')
      .attr('id', 'clip2')
      .append('rect')
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr('y', 0)
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height);

    chartArea.append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'bg')
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr('y', 0)
      .attr('width', this.chartWidth)
      .attr('height', this.chartHeight);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
    var xAxisG = chartArea.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'x-axis')
      .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`);

    xAxisG.call(xAxis);

    d3.selectAll('x-axis path').style('stroke', 'red')
      .style('stroke-width', 2);

    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
    var yAxisG = chartArea.append('g').attr('class', 'y-axis');
    yAxisG.call(yAxis);

    var grids = chartArea.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'grid')
      .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickSize(-(width)).tickFormat((domain, number) => {
        return ""
      }));

    var pathsG = chartArea.append('g')
      .attr('id', 'paths')
      .attr('class', 'paths')
      .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip2)');

    tick();

    function tick() {
      console.log('working');
      var newValue = {
        time: ++t,
        value: Math.random() * 10
      };

      data.push(newValue);

      xScale.domain([newValue.time - n + 2, newValue.time]);

      xAxisG.transition().duration(500).ease(d3.easeLinear).call(xAxis);
      console.log('is it?');


      var minerG = pathsG.selectAll('.minerLine').data([data]);
      var minerGEnter = minerG.enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'minerLine')
        .merge(minerG);



      var minerSVG = minerGEnter.selectAll('path').data((d) => [d]);



      var minerSVGEnter = minerSVG.enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .merge(minerSVG)
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .ease(d3.easeLinear, 2)

        .attr('d', line(data))

        .on('end', () => {
          requestAnimationFrame(tick)
        })


    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the fact that `tick` is called immediately and synchronously at the end of the transition. The CPU process executing the JavaScript remains busy updating data and chart, and is not available to do anything else on this tab.

One way to fix this is to use [`Window.requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

```
.on('end', () => {
    requestAnimationFrame(tick)
})
```

The updated snippet below shows this solution in action.

It does not fix other issues not mentioned in the question, like the fact that no data is shown in the chart.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js">
    
  </script>
  <script>
    var t = -1;
    var n = 40;
    var duration = 750;

    var data = [];

    console.log('hello');
    function next() {
      return {
        time: ++t,
        value: Math.random() * 10
      }
    }

    var margin = {
        top: 6,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 20,
        left: 40
      },
      width = 560 - margin.right,
      height = 120 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain([t - n + 1, t])
      .range([0, width]);

    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 10])
      .range([height, 0]);

    var line = d3.line()
      .x((d) => xScale(d.time))
      .y((d) => yScale(d.value));

    var svg = d3.select('body').append('p').append('svg');

    var chartArea = svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

    chartArea.append('defs').append('clipPath')
      .attr('id', 'clip2')
      .append('rect')
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr('y', 0)
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height);

    chartArea.append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'bg')
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr('y', 0)
      .attr('width', this.chartWidth)
      .attr('height', this.chartHeight);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
    var xAxisG = chartArea.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'x-axis')
      .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`);

    xAxisG.call(xAxis);

    d3.selectAll('x-axis path').style('stroke', 'red')
      .style('stroke-width', 2);

    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
    var yAxisG = chartArea.append('g').attr('class', 'y-axis');
    yAxisG.call(yAxis);

    var grids = chartArea.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'grid')
      .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickSize(-(width)).tickFormat((domain, number) => {
        return ""
      }));

    var pathsG = chartArea.append('g')
      .attr('id', 'paths')
      .attr('class', 'paths')
      .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip2)');

    tick();

    function tick() {
      console.log('working');
      var newValue = {
        time: ++t,
        value: Math.random() * 10
      };

      data.push(newValue);

      xScale.domain([newValue.time - n + 2]);

      xAxisG.transition().duration(500).ease().call(xAxis);
      console.log('is it?');


      var minerG = pathsG.selectAll('.minerLine').data([data]);
      var minerGEnter = minerG.enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'minerLine')
        .merge(minerG);



      var minerSVG = minerGEnter.selectAll('path').data((d) => [d]);



      var minerSVGEnter = minerSVG.enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .merge(minerSVG)
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .ease(d3.easeLinear, 2)

        .attr('d', line(data))

        .on('end', () => {
          requestAnimationFrame(tick)
        })


    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I had just one more thing, I edited my code above and now the x axis is moving as I wanted. But the time ticks displayed by d3 are in the format .005, .010 (The first data point is 10AM for some reason) and so on. Is there a way to tell D3 to display the x axis numbers as just seconds?

Comment: You can format the x axis when it is called. Here is some more information on that. https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9764126. However I don't see a simple way to convert .0010 to AM/PM format.

Comment: Thanks for that!